In a class body, is it safe to use vars() to dynamically set an attribute?
In Python, I can use vars() to dynamically set class attributes
class A:
    vars()['x'] = 1

print(A.x)  # Prints 1

However, the documentation for vars() states

Without an argument, vars() acts like locals(). Note, the locals dictionary is only useful for reads since updates to the locals dictionary are ignored.

This indicates updates to vars() shouldn't have any effect, but they clearly do based on the example above. The documentation for locals() similarly states

Note: The contents of this dictionary should not be modified; changes may not affect the values of local and free variables used by the interpreter.

This is slightly different from the var() documentation, as it states updates may not affect local variables, while the vars() documentation claims it doesn't affect local variables at all.
Is it safe to keep relying on using vars() to set class attributes? Or am I relying on unspecified behavior by doing this?

Why do you want to do that in the first place? XY question?

Relevant discussion on GitHub issue python/cpython#78931.

When I've needed to do things like this, I first define the class, then immediately after the class definition, I set the attributes that I couldn't set earlier, e.g. setattr(A, 'x', 1), which is equivalent to A.x = 1.  This is guaranteed to work.

Consider making a posting on codereview.stackexchange.com (read their site guidelines first though!) where you explain what you want to achieve and how your current solution works. I believe that could give a deeper insight into the matter.

My motivation is to programmatically define Enum values in an Enum subclass, similar to the GitHub issue link above. The bug author in the GitHub issue states
"So far, if I wanted to add methods to the Choice enum (e.g. for simplifying the code in callback), I could do it directly; if I wanted to dynamically generate the list of choices, I could also do it (by using the functional API). But to do both, it would have been nice to use the locals().update approach in the bug report above."
I have the same motivation.

In the very early versions of Python, all namespaces, whether in functions, classes or modules, were all implemented as a dictionary.
But for performance reasons, since Python 1.0, the implementation of function namespaces was changed to use the STORE_FAST and LOAD_FAST bytecodes to access local variables as indices in an array instead. A call to locals() from a function returns a dictionary that is created on the fly from the array of local variables.
This means that the dictionary returned by locals() and the actual array storing local variables may get out of sync with each other. Writes to the locals() dictionary may not show up as modifications to local variables. And writes to local variables may not be reflected in the locals() dictionary obtained earlier. This is why you see the notes in the documentation of locals() and vars() that updates to the dictionary returned by the call may not affect the actual local variables.
However, the STORE_FAST and LOAD_FAST bytecodes were implemented only for functions, not classes or modules, which is why you are observing the behavior that changes made to the dictionary returned by a call to locals()/vars() from a class are reflected in the resulting namespace of the class. So even though the behavior is technically undocumented, it is something that has not changed since the beginning of Python.
Moreover, since Python 3.13, with the implementation of PEP-667, access to the f_locals attribute of a frame now returns a proxy mapping to the array of local variables, guaranteeing that writes to f_locals can now be reflected in actual local variables, and vice versa. For backwards compatibility though, a call to locals() from a function returns a snapshot of f_locals rather than the proxy mapping itself. But this is a clear sign that Python developers intend to improve the consistency between locals() and the local namespace rather than the other way around, so I believe you can indeed keep relying on using locals()/vars() to set class attributes for the foreseeable future.

That's not quite what PEP 667 does. Even with PEP 667, writes to locals() are not always reflected in the underlying scope. Writes to f_locals are, but writes to locals() aren't, for optimized scopes. However, class scopes are not optimized scopes, so writing to locals() in a class body is fine.

Ah you're right. Thanks for the correction.

Thank you! I see the 3.13 prerelease documentation directly states mutations to locals() (and therefore vars()) will now have an effect in class bodies. So it looks like this behavior is safe and specified in 3.13.
